# How to consume multiple binding WCF Service method without mentioning the endpoint name

Tags: wcf-binding

Currently I’m using BaciHttpBinding and WsHttpBindin for same Service. Before introduce the BasicHttpBing, My Client Windows app consuming the WsHttpBindin, so i didn't mention the endpoint name. After introduce the BasicHttpBinding i need to mension the Name of the endpoint in my client when it going to consume the Desired Service. My problem is, I have to change all the existing code with endpoint name. How can i overcome this situation or is there any method which i can set the default binding in config level and it'll use when i didn't supply the endpoint name.

Answer (score 0):

You can not define multiple endpoints on same address, assign two different address for both the bindings.
You can leave the address blank in case of contracts and it will automatically points to the address of mex endpoint, which is being used for defining your metadata.
Similarly you can BindingConfiguration tag to configure the bindings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. My actual problem is upload the file(stream) to database through WCF service method. So By default i have used WsHttpBinding. But it didn't support for large volume file (Couldn't succeeded increase the message receive buffer and Reader quta values).That's why i was introduce BasicHttpBinding.It's work properly according to the increase of required values in config file (Server and client).I want to know, is this the way that WsHttp and BasicHttp Behave or any other reason?

Comment: Tara streaming can be done in any binding its mainly the mode which decide it

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, i am using binding configuration and transmode is streamed and using this binding configuration in my endpoints

```
<binding name="StreamBinding" closeTimeout="00:59:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
 sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="700000000" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
 <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="1000" />
 <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="02:00:00" />
 <security mode="None"></security>  </binding>
```

`<endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamBinding"
    bindingName="" contract="DBSInterface.Common.IFileTransfer">
    <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
</endpoint>`

Comment: This is ok for netTCP binding.But i'm using WsHttpBinding.maxBufferSize and transferMode attributes are not allow in WsHttpBinding.